# Getting conversion error while running a procedure - Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, utl-file, ora-06512

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE read_file IS
  f_line     VARCHAR2(2000);
  f          utl_file.file_type;
  comma1     VARCHAR(10);
  comma2     VARCHAR(10);
  comma3     VARCHAR(10);
  comma4     VARCHAR(10);
  comma5     VARCHAR(10);
  f_empno    emp.empno%TYPE;
  f_ename    emp.ename%TYPE;
  f_job      emp.job%TYPE;
  f_mgr      emp.mgr%TYPE;
  f_hiredate emp.doj%TYPE;
  f_sal      emp.sal%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    f := utl_file.fopen('LOG_FILES', 'ab1.txt', 'r');

    LOOP
      BEGIN
        utl_file.get_line(f, f_line);
        EXCEPTION WHEN no_data_found THEN EXIT;
      END;
      comma1 := INSTR(f_line, ',', 1, 1);
      comma2 := INSTR(f_line, ',', 1, 2);
      comma3 := INSTR(f_line, ',', 1, 3);
      comma4 := INSTR(f_line, ',', 1, 4);
      comma5 := INSTR(f_line, ',', 1, 5);

      f_empno := to_number(SUBSTR(f_line, 1, comma1 - 1));
      f_ename := SUBSTR(f_line, comma1 + 1, comma2 - comma1 - 1);
      f_job := SUBSTR(f_line, comma2 + 1, comma3 - comma2 - 1);
      f_mgr := to_number(SUBSTR(f_line, comma3 + 1, comma4 - comma3 - 1));
      f_hiredate := to_date(SUBSTR(f_line, comma4 + 1, comma5 - comma4 - 1), 'dd-mon-yyyy');
      f_sal := to_number(SUBSTR(f_line, comma5 + 1), '99999');

      dbms_output.put_line(f_empno || ' ' || f_ename || ' ' || f_job || ' ' || f_mgr || ' ' || f_hiredate || ' ' || f_sal);

      INSERT INTO emp12 VALUES (f_empno, f_ename, f_job, f_mgr, f_hiredate, f_sal);
    END LOOP;

    utl_file.fclose(f);

    COMMIT;
  END read_file;
  /
```

If I execute the program in sql command prompt as `exec read_file;`

I got error message as:

```
BEGIN read_file; END;

*

ERROR at line 1:

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.READ_FILE", line 34

ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Comment: remove all data type conversions (to_number etc), for example `f_empno := SUBSTR(f_line, 1, Comma1-1)` And write, what you see in dbms_output window

Comment: @Tatiana still giving the same error

Comment: If I remove f_sal from this procedure I am getting blank rows in table emp12. Please solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

```
f := utl_file.fopen('UTL_FILE_DIR',fname,'r');
```

`UTL_FILE_DIR` should be a directory which you created earlier.
For example

```
CREATE DIRECTORY UTL_FILE_DIR AS 'C:\LOG_FILES';
```

After it you can use this directory in utl_file.fopen. It will read file from UTL_FILE_DIR directory which is C:\LOG_FILES now.

You should create it only once, before you execute the procedure

And I think you don't need `f_dir` in that case

Comment: thanks for your answer but i am still getting a problem

Comment: f_sal := to_number(SUBSTR(f_line, comma5+1),'99999'); - 'getting numeric or value' error in this when i run the procedure

Comment: check, what you have in f_line variable. E.g. use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(f_line ||' '||SUBSTR(f_line, comma5+1)) to see what is stored in variable and what it is after substr. Looks like you get character, which you can't convert to number

Comment: can't understood what you want to say

Comment: what you expected to see in f_line variable?

Comment: I have expected to put value from my text file into f_line

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear.

If you want to execute it in SQL command prompt (sqlplus.exe) you can use

```
exec read_file;
```

If you want to execute it inside some other program then you need to specify which programming language you're using. The answer will vary depending on that.

Comment: I want to execute it in sql command prompt but just writing exec read_file give an error

Comment: @Abhinav What kind of error? How do you run it? Please provide this information in your question (use the *Edit* button).

Comment: BEGIN read_file; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29280: invalid directory path
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 33
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 436
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.READ_FILE", line 15
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: That means that directory UTL_FILE_DIR is not defined. Use the CREATE DIRECTORY syntax do define it.  Then again, it looks like your procedure is reading and parsing some text in order to load its content into a file. That is probably better done by defining an external table onto that file and loading its content using a simple INSERT ... SELECT.

Comment: where I should define UTL_FILE_DIR

Comment: @Abhinav execute CREATE Directory command on the command line before executing the procedure e.g. CREATE DIRECTORY log_files AS 'C:\LOG_FILES' and replace 'UTL_FILE_DIR' in the fopen call with 'log_files'
Also remove f_dir assignment from your procedure, you don't require it any longer.

Comment: still getting a problem

Comment: f_sal := to_number(SUBSTR(f_line, comma5+1),'99999'); - getting 'numeric or value' error in this when i run the procedure

Comment: please provide the complete error description along with the error number

Comment: BEGIN read_file; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.READ_FILE", line 28
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: can you please add `ab1.txt` file's contents to the question description?

Answer (score 0):

In **SQL*Plus**:

```
EXEC[UTE] procedure_name;
```

To call it within **PL/SQL**:

```
BEGIN
   procedure_name;
END;
/
```